# Active quotes with csquotes, polyglossia and xelatex not working

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, csquotes, german, quotation

I can't get german quotation marks to work with csquotes, polyglossia and xelatex.
It used to work a couple of weeks ago, but now it doesn't anymore.
I want to use `"` as an active quote character.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[babelshorthands=false]{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{german}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}

"Quote"

\enquote{Quote}

\end{document}
```

which gives me:

[image]

Only the enquote-command seems to work. What am I missing?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously similar to https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/421. (*edit*: Yep, the issue is no longer present with the `dev` branch of `polyglossia`.)

Comment: oh thank you! didn't quite know where to look... manually editing the gloss-german.ldf file as mentioned in the thread did the trick meanwhile. i'd happily accept is an answer if you like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the bug reported in https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/421 (and https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues/44).

The issue has already been fixed in the development version of `polyglossia` available on GitHub (https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia), but the version with the fix is not yet on CTAN.

While you are waiting for the fixed version to be released, you can get the fixed version of `gloss-german.ldf` from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/af00c264a4c694bb05e4c910912419281e88ea7d/tex/gloss-german.ldf (which is all you need here if you only write in German) and drop it into the same folder as your current project. **Remember to delete the file when `polyglossia` is updated.** (Alternatively, you could also update/overwrite the system-installed `gloss-german.ldf`, which is usually an absolute no-go, but just anticipates the coming update. The advantage is that the file should be overwritten with the new version during the update, so that you don't have to worry about taking care of the file.)